# Change the value's font color of an `ybar stacked` with `nodes near coords`

Tags: pgfplots

I'm struggling with how the change the font color of the values of my stacked bar. Right now it uses the same color of its bar but as the bar's color is light it doesn't display well as you can see on the following screenshot.

[image]

Looking at the documentation I found how to change the color to the labels and legend but what I want.

Any suggestion about how can change the font color?

Thanks in advanced,

Humberto

---

Here is a simple demo of my current scenario.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{magicmint}{rgb}{0.67, 0.94, 0.82}
\definecolor{columbiablue}{rgb}{0.61, 0.87, 1.0}
\definecolor{lavenderblue}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 1.0}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9,}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,nodes near coords,
    bar width=0.4, 
    ]
    \addplot+ [ybar, magicmint!80!black, fill=magicmint] coordinates
        {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
    \addplot+ [ybar, columbiablue!80!black, fill=columbiablue] coordinates
        {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
    \addplot+ [ybar, lavenderblue!80!black, fill=lavenderblue] coordinates
        {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)}; \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the text color to black, use `text=black` as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{magicmint}{rgb}{0.67, 0.94, 0.82}
\definecolor{columbiablue}{rgb}{0.61, 0.87, 1.0}
\definecolor{lavenderblue}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 1.0}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9,}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,nodes near coords,
    bar width=0.4, 
    ]
    \addplot+ [ybar, magicmint!80!black, fill=magicmint, text=black] coordinates
        {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
    \addplot+ [ybar, columbiablue!80!black, fill=columbiablue, text=black] coordinates
        {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
    \addplot+ [ybar, lavenderblue!80!black, fill=lavenderblue, text=black] coordinates
        {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)}; \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @leadriis 